# VirtualBox, Eraser, disk space not reclaimed

Tags: windows-7

I used the FOSS program Eraser to securely delete a VM folder under *VirtualBox VMs*. That VM folder and its contents were 6GB. All was securely Erased. However, when using Windows Explorer to examine the properties of my C: drive both before and after using Eraser, I see that my free disk space did not increase. Rebooting did not help.

I also used WInDirStat before and after Erasing. That program does show the *VirtualBox VMs* folder was reduced by 6GB. It also shows that the C: drive reduced by 6GB.

How do I get Windows to recognize and reclaim that 6GB disk space? Thanks.

Win7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Hallelujah! I ran chkdsk and now the missing disk space has shown up - plus 12GB more that had failed to show even earlier today plus some extra that I hadn't been aware was missing. The Explorer Properties window shows free space up from 48.0GB to 72.1GB. Here is the output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is OSDisk.

WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  515840 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  2224 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  76 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
  685668 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  515840 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  84915 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  33853112 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

 298231807 KB total disk space.
 249610712 KB in 379308 files.
    227880 KB in 84916 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1082283 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  47310932 KB available on disk.

  4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  74557951 total allocation units on disk.
  11827733 allocation units available on disk.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

That answers the question of how to fix. Still, it seems odd that the report is `47310932 KB available on disk.` Yet look at this:
[OSDisk (C:) Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK0J6.jpg) which now after chkdsk finally shows 77 giga bytes free space. Maybe someone can explain why chkdsk apparently doesn't know that it freed up the disk space.